# How to make clear the difference between 0 and O?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

It's reasonably clear that there's a difference between the lowercase "o" and "0", but it's harder to tell with a uppercase "O" and "0".

When saying them, certainly in the UK, "Oh" can be both o and zero.

If I'm trying to say zero it's clear, but if I'm trying to say o, how do I convey that clearly? And the same for typed emails using default fonts etc?

For my specific case, the company name is ia2o ltd... Pronounced aye eh too oh. Sadly there's no clear context here.

Comment: There are typefaces which make the distinction clearer, such as  `oO0` and `Il1`

Comment: But how to make the distinction in speech? And default fonts as the recipient may not have any special fonts installed... Edited for clarity

Comment: For my specific case, the company name is ia2o ltd... Pronounced aye eh too oh. Sadly there's no clear context here.

Comment: Sorry Ricky... *shrug*

Comment: [India Alfa Two Oscar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet)

Comment: Edited... Feel free to edit the question, it is SO after all.

Comment: You would still say "oh". At any point when there's numbers and letters involved together we go out of our way to say "zero" for a zero (really, we only say "oh" for zero in maths). If there's any confusion it's the fault of the listener (ia20 would've been pronounced eye-aye-twenty anyway).

Comment: @Julia, "oh" is also common for zero in phone numbers and other contexts where the single syllable helps reading aloud to scan (e.g. bank details), at least in this bit of the UK.

Comment: Speaking: I sometimes hear "letter oh".

Comment: Is it too late to maroon (on a desert island) the guy who invented the name ia2o?

Comment: @GEdgar "letter oh" would be a good answer. Sadly, the name was in part due to the vast amount of squatters on any reasonable domain name out there, so stuck with it for the foreseeable future...

Comment: I was about to suggest also buy the domain for ia20.com as well as your existing ia2o.com BUT I see that boat has sailed ! I like the idea of marooning the person responsible for the brand name!

Answer (score 4):

Three cases pertain: speaking, handwriting, typing.

1. For speaking, say "small oh".
2. Handwrite a distinct small oh.
3. Use a font that produces a distinct small o, or use an inline graphic for the entire company name. If needed (for customers who use email without inline graphics capability), follow the inline graphic with the company name in parentheses (ia2o ltd.).

This answer is brought to you by personal experience.

4. Take over and rename the company.

Comment: Regarding #3, you can use a slashed zero in some cases, though obviously that's not applicable for ia2o.com ! See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashed_zero